# Flutter just_audio package cannot file assets on Android

Tags: android, flutter, just-audio

I am trying to play audio using just_audio package, It work on chrome but when I try on android it is not working

I am getting this error: Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/sounds/correct_answer.mp3: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory).

Code:

```
   _player.setFilePath('assets/sounds/incorrect_answer.mp3');               
   _player.play();
```

Comment: Provide your code also!

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

```dart
await _player.setAsset('path/to/asset.mp3');
```

Option 2:

```dart
await _player.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri('asset:///path/to/asset.mp3'));
```